# Globally Declared Variable Returning Null After Method Call

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to create a LinkedList in C#. I am new to this. Would you please help me here?
What I am trying to do is: I have created Node type head and lastNode variables and trying to add node to every previous node by checking for the lastnode through `GetLastNode()` method. Although, every time I try to add second element, head turns null on reaching `GetLastNode()`. I am not sure why this is happening. Please help me understand the concept I am missing out.

```
class MyLinkedList
    {
        Node head, lastNode; 
        
        public void Add(int new_value)
        {
            Node new_node = new Node(new_value);                
            MyLinkedList obj = new MyLinkedList();
            lastNode = obj.GetLastNode();
            if(lastNode == null)
            {
                lastNode = new_node;
                this.head = new_node;
            }                  
            
            else
            {
                lastNode.next = new_node;
            }
        }
        public Node GetLastNode()
        {
            Node currentNode = this.head;
            if (currentNode == null)
                lastNode = currentNode;
            else
                while (currentNode != null)
                {
                    lastNode = currentNode;
                    currentNode = currentNode.next;
                }
            
            return lastNode;

        }
    }
```

Comment: please show us Node class

Comment: It looks like you're creating a new linked list every time `Add()` is called. Why is that?

Comment: Your `head` field isn't global, it's property of `MyLinkedList`, every time you create new `MyLinkedList`, calling `GetLastNode()` will use  you'r new `MyLinkedList`'s `head` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head` and `lastNode` are not global they are [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) which will differ for every instance of `MyLinkedList`. In `Add` your a creating a new (with the `new` keyword) instance of `MyLinkedList` which return `null` for `GetLastNode()` and assign this `null` to current `lastNode`, so you will end up with `null` for your current `lastNode` before `if`:

```cs
MyLinkedList obj = new MyLinkedList();
lastNode = obj.GetLastNode();
```

I would say you can just delete this lines.

Also it seems that `GetLastNode` should just return `lastNode` cause you are already doing all the needed tracking on `Add`:

```cs
public Node GetLastNode()
{
    return lastNode;
}
```

Comment: @AbhaJha was glad to help!